# MySQL summing amounts when overlapping date ranges are occuring

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble even knowing where to start for a query like this. Basically I'm given a database with certain amounts, and my boss wants me to transform this SQL data into a view. I'm in way over my head and don't know where to start or how to accomplish what I need to accomplish :(

I have a table like this:

```
record_id    amount    start_date    end_date
1            20000     2018-01-01   2018-12-01
1            -15000    2018-02-01   2018-04-01
1            50000     2018-04-02   2018-06-30
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
record_id    amount   start_date    end_date
1            20000    2018-01-01    2018-01-30
1            5000     2018-02-01    2018-04-01 
1            70000    2018-04-02    2018-06-30
1            20000    2018-07-01    2018-12-01
```

So on all overlapping date ranges, we calculate the sum and separate that into a new row. Once that date range is over we go back to the row that extended out to December. This is just one example, and the rows are tied by a unique `record_id`, and will have different amounts and date ranges. Some rows won't even overlap.

How do I even begin to write a query like this? Is MySQL the right choice for this?

Comment: MySQL (unless version 8) is not optimal for this problem.  What other choices do you have?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can use PHP (the system it will end up in) or if easier, I can use Python, and import it back into MySQL

Comment: does the record_id corresponds to a specific date range. eg: 2018-01-01 - 2018-12-31. All the records whose record_id is 1 will have dates that fall in the date range (2018-01-01 - 2018-12-31)

Comment: How do you get 70000 and 20000?

Comment: @Eric The overlapping date ranges are summed up, so the 50,000 + 20,000 = 70,000. After the 70,000 date range ends, it goes back down to 20,000

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split this up.

Use the MySQL to query for the data, but what you want to do requires quite a bit of processing.

I would look into utilizing some Object oriented languages (PHP, C#, Python) to take care of all the logic of trying to calculate the sums.