# Sum and segment overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our HR system specifies employee assignments, which can be concurrent. Our rostering system only allows one summary assignment for a person. Therefore I need to pre-process the HR records, so rostering can determine the number of shifts a worker is expected to work on a given day.

Looking just at worker A who has two assignments, the first is for a quarter shift and the second for a half shift, but overlapping in the middle where they work .75 shifts.

```
Person StartDate EndDate Shifts
   A   01/01/21  04/01/21   .25
   A   03/01/21  06/01/21   .5

      01---02---03---04---05---06---07
Rec 1 |------------------|
Rec 2 |        |===================|
Total |  0.25  |   0.75  |   0.5   |
```

Required output.

```
Person StartDate EndDate  ShiftCount
   A   01/01/21  02/01/21   0.25
   A   03/01/21  04/01/21   0.75
   A   05/01/21  06/01/21   0.5
```

Given this data, how do we sum and segment the data? I found an exact question for MySQL but the version was too early and code was suggested. I also found a Postgres solution but we don't have ranges.

```
select * from (
values 
('A','01/01/21','04/01/21',0.25),
('A','03/01/21','05/01/21',0.5)
) AS Data (Person,StartDate,EndDate,Shifts);
```

Comment: Looked at many, many examples. What the examples don't show is the creation of the third record, using start date of the second record. I read about doing a union of group by start date and end date but wasn't sure how it might apply.

Comment: You've found examples for 2 other RDBMS... have a crack at converting them, and if its not quite right, then post.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect these particular 3 ranges in the output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen rostering can only have one record for any given day, therefore it needs to be the accumulation of the overlapping ranges, so that it knows how many shifts are required on that day.

Comment: What is wrong with the MySQL solution you found?  Can you include a link to that?

Comment: Regarding the [MySQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792269/mysql-summing-amounts-when-overlapping-date-ranges-are-occuring) Gordon Linoff said MySQL (unless version 8) was not optimal and no solution was presented. The postgres solution uses date ranges, which SQL doesn't have any my attempt at a conversion doesn't yield the third row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a Gaps-and-Islands to me.

If it helps, `cte1` is used to expand the date ranges via an ad-hoc tally table.  Then `cte2` is used to create the Gaps-and-Islands.  The final result is then a small matter of aggregation.

**Example**

```
Set Dateformat DMY

Declare @YourTable table (Person varchar(50),StartDate Date,EndDate date,Shifts decimal(10,2))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('A','01/01/21','04/01/21',0.25)
,('A','03/01/21','05/01/21',0.5)


;with cte1 as (
Select [Person]
      ,[d] = dateadd(DAY,N,StartDate)
      ,Shifts = sum(Shifts)
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  (
        Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null))
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
       ) B on N <= datediff(DAY,[StartDate],[EndDate])
 Group By Person,dateadd(DAY,N,StartDate)
 ), cte2 as (
 Select *
      ,Grp    = datediff(day,'1900-01-01',d)-row_number() over (partition by Person,Shifts Order by d)
  From cte1
)
Select Person
      ,StartDate = min(d)
      ,EndDate   = max(d)
      ,Shifts    = max(Shifts)
  From cte2
  Group By Person,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Person  StartDate   EndDate     Shifts
A       2021-01-01  2021-01-02  0.25
A       2021-01-03  2021-01-04  0.75
A       2021-01-05  2021-01-05  0.50
```

Comment: Yes but gaps and islands examples don't create that third record, whereas yours does. Thx.

Comment: @strattonn You may notice cte1.  This is where I expand the date ranges.

Comment: Yes I was just looking at the 1000 N, I just need to set N to cover the greatest span of assignments start and end date. I've just checked, the longest are around 4,000 days. Shouldn't be an issue. There's one at 11,000 days but I think I need to check the data.

Comment: @strattonn  rather than Top 1000 ... simply make it TOP 25000  (it will do no harm)

Comment: Done, master..spt_values has 2,560 rows, spt_values x spt_values is 6.5M rows, so no limitation there. Nice trick for getting a number range, will use that again.

Comment: @strattonn Just to be clear... any table of appropriate size would do.   spt_values is just a know table.